# How to substitute a space and special characters in C#? And how to hide them when they are not needed?

Tags: c#, string, class, methods, console-application

I am trying to substitute spaces and special characters using a private const string in C# namely [SPACE] for spaces and [UPPER] for ---. I used another class to achieve this. However, simultaneous or more than one substitution doesn't seem to work (e.g substituting [UPPER] and [SPACE] is not working]

Here is the output of the code with string [UPPER].
[Image with --- character, [UPPER]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq1G1.png)

Here is the one with string [SPACE]
[Image with spaces, [Space]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlqWU.png)

And here is the code:
(The code for the Image (the one responsible for the ASCII) will be in the comment section, for some reason, it continuously says that it is not formatted as code)

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CatAndEgg.PrintImageWithSpaces(0, 9);
        Task.Delay(200).Wait();
        CatAndEgg.PrintImageWithUpperFence(9, 10);
        Task.Delay(200).Wait();
        Console.Read();
    }
    public static class CatAndEgg
    {
        private const string ReplacementString = "[SPACES]";
        private const string UpperFenceString = "[UPPER]";
        private const string Image = @"             [SPACES]       _,'|             _.-''``-...___..--';
```

[UPPER] [SPACES]        /_ \'.      __..-' ,      ,--...--'''
___ [SPACES]        <\    .`--'''`            /'
/   [SPACES]          `-';'               ;   ; ;
|’    |[SPACES]  **...--''     ***...--*..'  .;.'
_**/ [SPACES](,**....----'''       (,..--'' ";

```
        public static void PrintImageWithSpaces(int numberOfSpaces, int upperFence)
        {
            string spaces = new string(' ', numberOfSpaces);
            string uFence = new string('-', upperFence);
            Console.Write(Image.Replace(ReplacementString, spaces), Image.Replace(UpperFenceString, uFence));
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public static void PrintImageWithUpperFence(int upperFence, int numberOfSpace)
        {
            string uFence = new string('-', upperFence),
                   uspaces = new string(' ', numberOfSpace);
            Console.Write(Image.Replace(UpperFenceString, uFence), Image.Replace(ReplacementString, uspaces));
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }


    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve this:
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ODCb.png)

Suppose I add a new string called [LOWER], how do I do its method?
And what if for instance, you want to hide the [UPPER] and [LOWER} and just what to show the spaces? How will you do it?

This is intentionally meant for a quiz console application by the way.

I am open to suggestions if there is a better way of solving this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: private const string Image = @"             [SPACES]       _,'|             _.-''``-...___..--';
  [UPPER] [SPACES]        /_ \\'.      __..-' ,      ,--...--'''
    ___ [SPACES]        <\\    .`--'''       `     /'
   /   \[SPACES]          `-';'               ;   ; ;
  |’    |[SPACES]  __...--''     ___...--_..'  .;.'
   \___/ [SPACES](,__....----'''       (,..--'' ";

Answer (score 1):

String.Replace does not modify the string it is working on. You have to use the return value.

Instead of:

```
Console.Write(Image.Replace(ReplacementString, spaces), Image.Replace(UpperFenceString, uFence));
```

Use the following:

```
string text = Image.Replace(ReplacementString, spaces);
Console.Write(text);
text = text.Replace(UpperFenceString, uFence);
Console.Write(text);
```

Comment: It worked!!! however, the space in the [FENCE] part ruined the orientation of the text

Comment: suppose I add a new string called [LOWER], how to do its method?

Comment: and what if for instance you want to hide the [UPPER] and [LOWER} and just what to show the spaces?

Comment: I need your help so badd

Comment: This seems like a time for a new question.